# Replace specific lines of a file with values of other file

Tags: awk, sed, replace

I would like to replace the 2nd, 6th, and 7th rows of `file1` with the values in each row of `file2` and generate a series of files equal to `wc -l file2`

```
cat file1
```

```
w
3
y
G
7
1.2
Q
```

```
cat file2
```

```
1        1        1
6        6        7
5        6        5
```

Desired outcomes:

```
cat out1
```

```
w
1
y
G
7
1
1
```

```
cat out2
```

```
w
6
y
G
7
6
7
```

```
cat out3
```

```
w
5
y
G
7
6
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
awk '
    FNR == NR { data[++n] = $0; next }
    {
        data[2] = $1; data[6] = $2; data[7] = $3;
        outname = sprintf("out%d", FNR)  # or: outname = "out" FNR
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            print data[i] >outname
        close(outname)
    }' file1 file2
```

This first reads `file1`, then `file2`.

While reading `file1` (the `FNR == NR` block), the only thing the `awk` code is doing is storing each line in the array `data`.

While reading `file2`, the code takes each each of the three fields on a line of that file and assigns them to the indexes in `data` corresponding to the lines that you want to change in `file1`.

The lines stored in `data` are then printed to a filename constructed by taking the current line number in `file2` and prepending the string `out` to it.

The `close(outname)` is only really needed if you are using an `awk` that is not GNU `awk`, and you're writing to more files than the limit on open file descriptors (more than what `ulimit -n` returns, minus three for the standard streams).

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
|-- file1
`-- file2

0 directory, 2 files
```

```
$ awk '
    FNR == NR { data[++n] = $0; next }
    {
        data[2] = $1; data[6] = $2; data[7] = $3;
        outname = sprintf("out%d", FNR)
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            print data[i] >outname
        close(outname)
    }' file1 file2
```

```
$ tree
.
|-- file1
|-- file2
|-- out1
|-- out2
`-- out3

0 directory, 5 files
```

```
$ paste out[123]
w       w       w
1       6       5
y       y       y
G       G       G
7       7       7
1       6       6
1       7       5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("2 6 7",tmp)
    for (fldNr in tmp) {
        map[tmp[fldNr]] = fldNr
    }
}
NR==FNR {
    rows[++numRows] = $i
    next
}
{
    out = "out" FNR
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        print (rowNr in map ? $(map[rowNr]) : rows[rowNr]) > out
    }
    close(out)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
```

```
$ head out?
==> out1 <==
w
1
y
G
7
1
1

==> out2 <==
w
6
y
G
7
6
7

==> out3 <==
w
5
y
G
7
6
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **GNU sed** we get the outputs in files out_0/1/2 for each line of file2.

```
tmpf=$(mktemp) i=0
while read -ra a <&3
do
   printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" > "$tmpf"
   sed -ne "
      $(printf '%dba\n' 2 6 7)
      p;d;:a
      R $tmpf
   " file1 > "out_$i"
    (( i++ ))
done 3< file2
```

- read file2 in a while loop and convert the fields from space separated to newline separated and store in a temp file.
- get sed to invoke the R command for line numbers 2,6,&7 of file1 to get the desired output.